# SQL Error with creating a sequence

Tags: java, sql, sqlite, syntax, sequence

The plugin i'm currently creating, HelpManager for Bukkit Minecraft, will require a database to be efficient, and this is my first time working with a database, on a plugin-level.

So I looked around and I've seen a few vague tutorials, and other tutorials requiring a dependency plugin to have the database work, which I do not want my users to have to download.

Here, I's successfully made 6 columns, but I needed a way to have a unique number (an ID) for each ticket, so I tried the following code:

```
" CREATE SEQUENCE if not exist ID" +
"(MINVALUE 1, START WITH 1, INCREMENT BY 1, CACHE 100)";
```

Here's the error:

```
2013-08-13 23:23:30 [SEVERE] java.sql.SQLException: near "CREATE": syntax error
2013-08-13 23:23:30 [SEVERE]    at org.sqlite.NativeDB.throwex(NativeDB.java:210)
2013-08-13 23:23:30 [SEVERE]    at org.sqlite.NativeDB._exec(Native Method)
2013-08-13 23:23:30 [SEVERE]    at org.sqlite.Stmt.executeUpdate(Stmt.java:152)
2013-08-13 23:23:30 [SEVERE]    at com.ahellhound.bukkit.helpmanager.Main.onEnable(Main.java:43)
2013-08-13 23:23:30 [SEVERE]    at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin.setEnabled(JavaPlugin.java:217)
2013-08-13 23:23:30 [SEVERE]    at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader.enablePlugin(JavaPluginLoader.java:457)
2013-08-13 23:23:30 [SEVERE]    at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.enablePlugin(SimplePluginManager.java:382)
2013-08-13 23:23:30 [SEVERE]    at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_6_R2.CraftServer.loadPlugin(CraftServer.java:286)
2013-08-13 23:23:30 [SEVERE]    at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_6_R2.CraftServer.enablePlugins(CraftServer.java:268)
2013-08-13 23:23:30 [SEVERE]    at net.minecraft.server.v1_6_R2.MinecraftServer.l(MinecraftServer.java:319)
2013-08-13 23:23:30 [SEVERE]    at net.minecraft.server.v1_6_R2.MinecraftServer.f(MinecraftServer.java:296)
2013-08-13 23:23:30 [SEVERE]    at net.minecraft.server.v1_6_R2.MinecraftServer.a(MinecraftServer.java:256)
2013-08-13 23:23:30 [SEVERE]    at net.minecraft.server.v1_6_R2.DedicatedServer.init(DedicatedServer.java:164)
2013-08-13 23:23:30 [SEVERE]    at net.minecraft.server.v1_6_R2.MinecraftServer.run(MinecraftServer.java:397)
2013-08-13 23:23:30 [SEVERE]    at net.minecraft.server.v1_6_R2.ThreadServerApplication.run(SourceFile:582)
```

Now if/when I get this working, I'll set the cache to maybe 3000, as I don't want the server to run out of unique ticket ID's.

I think there's a more efficient/logical way of doing this, I just haven't found it/learned about it.

Here's the full class:

```
public class Main extends JavaPlugin implements CommandExecutor, Listener {
Logger log = Logger.getLogger("Minecraft");
//Database Config
public String tableName = new String();


@Override
public void onEnable() {

reloadConfiguration();
saveDefaultConfig();
getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(this, this);
log.info("[" + getDescription().getName() + "] "
+ getDescription().getName() + " version "
+ getDescription().getVersion() + " is now enabled.");
log.info("[" + getDescription().getName() + "]" + " Made By AhellHound");

//Connecting to DB
Connection c = null;
java.sql.Statement stmt = null;
try {
Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:plugins" + File.separator + "HelpManager" + File.separator + "databse.db");
stmt = c.createStatement();
c.setAutoCommit(false);
String sql = "CREATE TABLE if not exists " + tableName +
" (ID INT UNIQUE NOT NULL, PlayerName TEXT NOT NULL, Message TEXT NOT NULL, Location TEXT, Priority NOT NULL, Viewed BOOLEAN NOT NULL)" +
" CREATE SEQUENCE if not exist seq_person" +
"(MINVALUE 1, START WITH 1, INCREMENT BY 1, CACHE 100)";
stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
stmt.close();
c.close();
} catch ( Exception e ) {
e.printStackTrace();
}

}

public void reloadConfiguration() {
//Config
tableName = new String();
tableName = getConfig().getString("tableName");
}

}
```

If you need anymore info, I'll gladly answer your questions.

Thanks for the help,
AhellHound

Comment: Did you try giving a space between "exist seq_person" and "(MINVALUE 1"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make your `ID` column a primary key and then set it to autoincrement

```
"CREATE TABLE if not exists " + tableName +
" (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, 
   PlayerName TEXT NOT NULL, 
   Message    TEXT NOT NULL, 
   Location   TEXT, 
   Priority NOT NULL, 
   Viewed BOOLEAN NOT NULL)"
```

[See here for a tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_using_autoincrement.htm)